# Comparing times on Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to check if a set of fields indicate times of the day that are before 11am. The dates are stored in this format: `8:42:00 AM`

I tried `A1<"11:00:00 AM"` but it always returns `True`, even if it was after 11am

Maybe a solution is convert it to Epoch first? or is there a more straight forward way? any working approach will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that "11:00:00 AM" is not a time value, it's just a string with characters 1, 1, :, 0, and so forth. You can convert it to a time value with [`timevalue`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350) function:

```
=A1<timevalue("11:00:00 AM")
```

or better yet, define the time directly with [`time`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093056)

```
 =A1<time(11, 0, 0)
```

The second approach is locale-independent; it does not rely on conventions such as AM/PM vs 24 hour clock.

Answer (score 0):

I had an instance where the time based formula above didn't work properly, I don't know if it had to do with a custom format being applied to the time column. The stored value for that column appears to be a timestamp, as such I had to use the following formula:

=((A1-int(A1))<time(11, 0, 0)